# swig perl typemap(out) std::vector<std::string> doesn't return the desired output in perl

Tags: c++, perl, swig

I am trying to type a typemap(out) std::vector.
I want it to get to the perl code as an array instead I am getting an array of arrays which after a double dereference contains the desired data.
how can I make it an array of strings in perl?

I have tried to edit the typemap myself and to use the typemaps in the "std_vector.i" and in "std_string.i" without editing and they all give the same results.

this is the typemap code:

```
%typemap(out) std::vector<std::string> {
        int len = $1.size();
        SV *svs = new SV[len];
        for (int x = 0; x < len; x++) {
                SV* sv = sv_newmortal();
                sv_setpvn(sv, $1[x].data(), $1[x].size());
                svs[x] = SvPV(sv, $1[x].size());
        }
        AV *myav = av_make(len, svs);
        delete[] svs;
        $result = newRV_noinc((SV*) myav);
        sv_2mortal($result);
        argvi++;
}
```

my code for testing the output:

```
#this return a std vector<string> in the cpp code
my @commitReturn = $SomeClass->commit();
        print "\n";
        #this should return a string instead it returns an array.
        print $commitReturn[0];
        print "\n";
        #this should not work, instead it returns the desired output.
        print $commitReturn[0][0];
```

the output is:

```
ARRAY(0x908c88)
20790
```

instead of:

```
20790
Can't use string ("20791") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `commit` method is just returning an array reference, not an array of array references. Maybe it looks like an array of array references because you are assigning the result to an array?

In any case, without touching the typemap code, you can dereference the function call

```
@commitReturn = @{$SomeClass->commit()};
```

or create a wrapper method to dereference it for you

```
package SomeClass;
...
sub commit_list {
    my $self = shift;
    @{$self->commit()};
}
...
@commitReturn = $SomeClass->commit_list();
```

Comment: They're expecting the code to return multiple strings, not a AoAoString, so should be: "Your `commit` method is returning a single scalar (a reference to an array), not multiple strings."

Comment: thank you, but I have an api that I can't change that uses the compiled swig file so I am looking for a typemap solution that will return what is expected. meaning just an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

To return an array instead of a reference to an array, you have to manipulate the stack such that Perl knows that more than one scalar is returned.

According to [the documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Perl5.html#Perl5):

> The current value of the argument stack pointer is contained in a
>   variable `argvi`. Whenever a new output value is added, it is critical
>   that this value be incremented. For multiple output values, the final
>   value of `argvi` should be the total number of output values.

So the following typemap should be sufficient:

```
%typemap(out) std::vector<std::string> {
    int len = $1.size();
    for (int x = 0; x < len; x++) {
        $result = sv_newmortal();
        sv_setpvn($result, $1[x].data(), $1[x].size());
        argvi++;
    }
}
```